# Execute an external exe from appdata

Tags: c++, windows, shellexecute

How can I execute an EXE file in the appdata folder without knowing the username of the path c:\users\username  ?

```c++
#include <stdio.h> // C library to perform Input/Output operations 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stddef.h> // C Standard definitions 
#include <iostream> // Input/Output
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
ShellExecute(NULL, "Open", "C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\mcv.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_HIDE);
}
```

Comment: Use `ExpandEnvironmentStrings ()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows environment variable %APPDATA%, which resolves to "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming" on Windows 10.

More info on Windows variables here :

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/help/folder-variables